# Get env variables inside _middleware Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

Inside my nextjs project I have variables added in both .env and next.conf.js files. Inside next.conf.js file it looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET: "...",
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET: "...",
    API_JWT_SECRET: process.env.API_JWT_SECRET,
  },
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET: "...",
    secondSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET, // Pass through env variables
  },
};
```

I have tried all this ways to get the secret ket in my _middleware file, but none of them worked. From [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30612#issuecomment-988148955) github issue I assume that there is a way to do that. So could you please show me the correct way to get secret ket inside _middleware?

Answer (score 1):

As [hugefunwoo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30612#issuecomment-955121722) says

> Next.js will replace process.env.customKey with 'my-value' at build time. Trying to destructure process.env variables won't work due to the nature of webpack DefinePlugin.

```
const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env
```

This will return undefind so I had to replace it by

```
const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET
```